# Data transforming: not recognising values in r

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new variable (`IMD_new`) in r which is based on the values of another variable (`IMD_raw`). The code I have written recognises some of the values in `IMD_raw`, but it fails to consistently work for one specific label ("1"). No error messages are produced. I have 400+ observations, with v small number of NAs. Here is an example dataframe (`data_IMD`) with current and expected outcomes:

**Current:**

```
ID   IMD_Raw   IMD_New
1    26022        3
2    7847         7847
3    12004        1
4    24622        2
5    8810         8810
```

**Anticipated**

```
    ID   IMD_Raw   IMD_New
1    26022        3
2    7847         1
3    12004        1
4    24622        2
5    8810         1
```

**Here is the code I am using:**

```
    data_IMD$IMD_New <- 1 
    data_IMD$IMD_New <- data_IMD$IMD_Raw 
    data_IMD$IMD_New[data_IMD$IMD_Raw >= 0 & data_IMD$IMD_Raw <"150242"] <- "1" 
    data_IMD$IMD_New[data_IMD$IMD_Raw >"150241" & data_IMD$IMD_Raw <="24683"] <- "2"
    data_IMD$IMD_New[data_IMD$IMD_Raw >24683 & data_IMD$IMD_Raw <="32831"] <- "3"
```

Any suggestions for what I'm doing wrong? For some reason it is failing to recognize that ID 2 should be classified as '1' because their `IMD_Raw` is greater than 0 and less than 150242. 


Thanks!

Comment: Make sure `IMD_RAW` is stored as numeric, rather than character. Then remove the quotes from your `>` and `<`conditions

Comment: Character strings will not behave as you would expect with `>` and `<`.

Comment: Thanks - this is true. I've also just seen that my numerical values in the code were wrong. The 3rd line has 6 digits, but it was meant to be 5. I've been staring at this for hours and didn't see it. Thanks for your help.